# odr-used rule does not apply in visual studio

Tags: c++, c++11, one-definition-rule

According to the [definition of `odr-used`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition%23One_Definition_Rule):

> Informally, an object is odr-used if its value is read (unless it is a compile time constant) or written, **its address is taken, or a reference is bound to it;** ..... If an object, a reference or a function is odr-used, its definition must exist somewhere in the program; **a violation of that is usually a link-time error.**

But here in visual studio 2015:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{
public:
    static const int k=666;
};

int main() {
    const int&s=A::k;//no warning?undefined behavior?
    cout << &A::k << endl;//no warning,no error?
    return 0;
}
```

According to cppref:

> **a definition outside of class is required if it is odr-used**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[[basic.def.odr]p10](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#10):

> Every program shall contain **exactly one definition** of every non-inline function or **variable that is odr-used** in that program outside of a discarded statement; **no diagnostic required**.

emphasis mine.

Comment: So is that an ill-formed code snippet which has undefined behavior?

Comment: @bigxiao It's not exactly the same thing. Your program is ill-formed, without any UB. But running it gives you no guarantees on what you could get.